# Удаление стандартных табов на странице продукта Magento

Tags: php, magento

Добрый день !

Есть страница продукта и на ней несколько стандартных вкладок: `description`, `product tags`, `reviews`!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

`description` таб я удалил, но другие удалить не удалось.

Пробовал [это](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/63154/remove-product-information-reviews-tags-block-from-product-page) и в `local.xml` вставлял:

```
<layout>
    <catalog_product_view>
        <remove name="product.reviews" />
    </catalog_product_view>
</layout>
```

**Но табы не пропадают!!!**

**Каким образом их можно удалить ?**

Comment: включи подсказки блоков в админке-> система -> конфигурация -> для разработчиков -> дебаг, переключившись на представление сайта в левом углу.

Comment: @Naumov, спасибо ! Это очень удобно, но все равно не могу понять что не так! вроде все правильно делаю

Comment: Что выводит...?

Comment: @Naumov, показывает какой блок для каждого таба

Comment: Ну и смотри в layout что за блок там и какое имя у него

Comment: @Naumov, нет не показывает блок самого таба, а блок того что открывается при нажатии на этот таб!

Comment: Значит tab находиться гдето в шаблоне product view определи в каком он шаблоне прописан и закоментируй его в своей теме

Comment: @Naumov,  Спасибо за помощь) нашел все и закомментировал - теперь все как надо !

Comment: @Naumov, странно конечно, что оно было в шаблоне! Все говорят, что им этот вариант помогал http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/63154/remove-product-information-reviews-tags-block-from-product-page

Comment: А какой шаблон использован стандартный rwd или какой то свой?

Comment: @Naumov, нет, не в  rwd )) а в кастомной теме шаблон !

Comment: ну тогда всё ок.